# GCM maximum frequency

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send a message every 30 sendonds to my with HIGH_PRIORITY. After each message delivery I want to make an HTTP get. Is there any limitation using the GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING? Will the device wake up from DOZE MODE and do the http get?

Comment: Are you sure you read this [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) to understand how apps enter doze mode and occasionally exit from it during a maintenance window then go back to doze under certain conditions? Also, if I had an Android device, I definitely wouldn't want / would uninstall apps that force a wake up and an HTTP request every 30 seconds.

Comment: It not a commercial app. It's just for me. Yes I am absolutely sure I want an http get every 30 seconds. The doze mode exits every 15 mins or more

Comment: Using high priority will wake the device from doze mode and give your app permission to make an HTTP request. I must reinforce that high priority should only be used for messages that require immediate user interaction like a chat msg.

Comment: Is it prohibited to use HIGH_PRIORITY if I don't want user interaction?

Comment: It is not prohibited however it is not recommended or published applications, if you are using it for testing then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nvm brain malfunction.  My original answer was incorrect. the best you can do with Alarms in doze is to use SetExactAllowWhileIdle. Those will go off every 15 minutes at best. The only way to do what you are describing is to have an event unaffected by Doze to trigger the logic to send a GCM message. As far as I know your only options are a BLE scan callback (obviously out of question) or if you set things up to receive a GCM message to your device every 30 seconds.  Upon receiving  a GCM message, you could send out another.

T̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶s̶c̶r̶i̶b̶i̶n̶g̶,̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶g̶n̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶b̶a̶t̶t̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶m̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶.̶ ̶O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶w̶i̶s̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶a̶l̶a̶r̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶w̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶3̶0̶ ̶s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶n̶ ̶D̶o̶z̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶m̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶t̶u̶r̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶a̶l̶a̶r̶m̶s̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶g̶o̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶ ̶o̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶1̶5̶ ̶m̶i̶n̶u̶t̶e̶s̶.̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶m̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶h̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶l̶i̶m̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶G̶o̶o̶g̶l̶e̶ ̶C̶l̶o̶u̶d̶ ̶M̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶s̶o̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶ ̶b̶e̶h̶a̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶

Comment: From the doze mode and whitelist documentation.
>>>However, other restrictions still apply to the whitelisted app, just as they do to other apps. For example, the whitelisted app’s jobs and syncs are deferred, and its regular AlarmManager alarms do not fire.<<<

Comment: @Giorgos Oikonomou Yes you are right. Ive actually tested this behavior a lot a while ago, but I was not thinking clearly when I typed that, sorry.